# An app is opening when i run python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a small menu with tkinker but every time I run it an application runs like chrome

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

root = Tk()
root.minsize(width=230, height=230)
root.maxsize(width=230, height=230)
root.configure(background='blue')
menubar = Menu(root)
root.title("alex")
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

b1 = Button(root, text = "chrome", command=os.startfile('c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'))
b1.place(x=30,y=30)

b2 = Button(root, text = "exit", command=exit)
b2.place(x=200,y=200)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a common mistake in tkinter. When referring to a function/method you do not include the `()`. If you need to pass arguments you can use a lambda expression. It is very useful. There are some other approaches as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating your button in the format you have, tkinter will execute the command you've passed it. An easy workaround is to create a lambda function that will be called when the button is pressed.

See below for your `b1` button definition:

```
b1 = Button(root, text="chrome", command=lambda:
    os.startfile(r'c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'))
```

Also note that calling `exit` isn't the cleanest way to quit your application. I'd recommend the following:

```
b2 = Button(root, text="exit", command=lambda: root.destroy)
```

Comment: thank you i am very new to python. i literally started today

Comment: would you like to help me to exit after i hit a button

Comment: What's your question? I'll see what I can do!

Comment: can i have the menu close after i press a button?

Comment: Use the same command in your menu exit button as you used for the b2 button - root.destroy - instead of exit.

Comment: where would i add it to on the string

Comment: Call menubar.destroy(). If you want both commands as part of one button you'll have to define a function at the beginning of your script with both commands (os.startfile and menubar.destroy) and define it as on_button_press() or something like that. Then set on_button_press as your button command.